# A person who thinks artistically and sees the world as a painting

Tags: single-word-requests

looking for a word that describes a person who is deeply moved by art and sees the world artistically?  a person who is hyper-aware of aesthetic beauty around them.

Comment: What's wrong with the adjective *artistic* itself?

Comment: In the US, an 'aesthetician' is a fancy word for a hairdresser.

Comment: Some might consider this person to be "right-brained" as opposed to "left-brained"

Answer (score 2):

In late Victorian times there was a movement known as [Aestheticism](https://www.bl.uk/romantics-and-victorians/articles/aestheticism-and-decadence) promoted by, among others, Oscar Wilde. The people who could be described a members or followers of the Aesthetic movement were called **Aesthetes** and believed that life itself could, and should, be an art form.

At the start of Wilde's novel "The Picture of Dorian Gray". in which a painting of a beautiful young man ages as he remains young, Dorian Gray is described as a 'young aesthete'.

The type of person you are describing could be called an **Aesthete**.

Comment: Just to throw in an actual definition in: (1866, *originally pejorative*) "A person who professes a special or superior appreciation of what is beautiful". The *OED* also notes its use in British universities as a synonym of swot.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion :) +1

Answer (score 0):

"Aesthete" is probably the *best* word you're looking for, but I'll just add that many adjectives can be used substantively in English and anything about perception will fit your bill. They'll have the connotation of someone who is *especially* perceptive and relation to appreciation will be pretty natural. In particular, since at least 1807,

## [Sensitive](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175988)

> 6. a. A person who is very susceptible or responsive to artistic or emotional impressions, *spec.* an aesthete; a person of a delicate or tender disposition. Also with *the* and *plural* agreement: such people collectively.

Also "sensitivist".

Answer (score -2):

You can call that person **Aesthetician<sup>1</sup>.**

Definition of [aesthetician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aesthetician) from Merriam Webster,

> 1 : a specialist in aesthetics (see AESTHETIC entry 2 sense 1)
>
> > 1. Encountering such designs, we have the aestheticians to tell us that they are rhythmic ways of filling space and of pleasing the eye.
> >        — Guy Davenpo
> > 2. For the aesthetician, wildlife art is an enigma of stability in a century of ever-changing trends.
> >        — Chuck Wechsler

So, Aesthetic entry 2 sense 1 is

> aesthetics also esthetics plural in form but singular or plural in construction : a branch of philosophy dealing with the nature of beauty, art, and taste and with the creation and appreciation of beauty.

---

<sup>1: In North America, Beautician is also called Aesthetician.</sup>

Comment: This would be a person who studies the philosophy of aesthetics, not an aesthete who appreciates it.

Comment: Also, fwiw, the *OED* doesn't mark the beautician sense as specifically (North/) American.